# How to get list of values using criteria API

Tags: jpa-2.0, openjpa

I have Entity classes as below. I am using open jpa.

```
Class RootClass{
 A a;
}
Class A{
  List<B> b;
}
Class B {
  C c;
}
Class C {
  String name;
}
```

When b was single object instead of list, I used the following statement to 
select name. It was working fine.

```
Root<RootClass> rootElement = myQuery.from(RootClass.Class);
    ... ...
Predicate predicate =  criteriaBuilder.equal(rootElement.get("a").get("b").get("c").  <String>get("name"),userName);
```

But when b is changed as a List, the above code doesn't work. Please provide some pointers on how to get list using Root.

Comment: Sorry for not formatting properly. I couldn't do it in mobile version of SO.

Comment: I'll format it for you

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `join` instead of `get`:

```
Root<RootClass> rootElement = myQuery.from(RootClass.Class);
...
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootElement.join("a").join("b").
    get("c").<String>get("name"), userName);
```